# How to clean database by GreenDAO

Tags: android, database, sqlite, greendao

I am very new for GreenDao . I just started one week ago on GreenDao. Now i have one problem , I have one android app that have approx 10MB data base , then i planed to store only last 30 day data  in mobile database. Then what happen my content of database get deleted or you can say sync to server but still it size getting increase day-by-day. That means database content get deleted but it doesn't release their occupied space in memory. So i want to clean up database. Even i search about vacuum , but as i told i didn't have any idea how to use it in GreenDAO. Thanks in advance to all .

Comment: Could you post the code. How are you reducing the data to the last 30 days?

Comment: @AlexS.. First thanks for your response. Sorry i cant post code because it contain lot of URL and it about 310 line of code. I hope you can understand and never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **TRUNCATE** query for delete all data and free space...

Comment: Thanks :).. But as i told i am very new for GeenDao and ORM framework . will please suggest me some tutorial from beginners level to advance level.?

Comment: @BlueGreen..hard to find document for GreenDao,if you dont read this http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/how-to-get-started/ then plz read first and download this [demo](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO)

Comment: @Umang.. I go through this official documentation but if i am working with ERP kind of project for android , then what you think is it helpful for me ? That is tragedy with me... bro... :( But really i am thanks-full for your response.

Comment: welcome man...please tell me why you use GreenDAO apart from ORMLite(another ORM) ..??

Comment: Yes man that is pain for me... As our client requirement:( ... I know i can find many tutorial on ORMLite.. But GreenDAO is Still VIRGIN..

Comment: Ok.. same here..Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: Cant find any mention of the word truncate in the GreenDao docs?